# Doxygen not creating call graphs for C# methods if namespace contains the classname

Tags: development

I am using Doxygen to create call and caller graphs for a large C# project which is a SharePoint 2010 solution. This solution has many components and I noticed that some of them (console applications for example) will happily create call graphs for the methods, but Workflows failed to create any call graphs.

After a lot of trying different settings, I found that Visual Studio templates for SharePoint workflows create a namespace directive in the file that also has the class name in it. So some pseudo code might look as follows:

```
namespace ProjectDefaultNamespace.Workflow1
public sealed partial class Workflow1 : SequentialWorkflowActivity
{
  public Workflow1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  private void onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
      doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

This creates an assembly with a class name of ProjectDefaultNamespace.Workflow1.Workflow1 and that repeating "Workflow1" is enough to throw Doxygen off the scent.

If I remove the trailing ".Workflow1" from all of the namespace declarations in the solution (and fix up all the other bits that this breaks) Doxygen starts creating graphs again.

Is this a bug? Or have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, can you file a bug report (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen) and attach a self-contained example that allows me to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Just noticed your comment - I have filed a bug report now with two sample projects - one that works and one that doesn't.